# Shiro Java DefaultWebSessionManager Session

Tags: java, session, shiro

I have a question regarding to the shiro session management.
1 Is DefaultWebSessionManager session manager store session in Ehcache by default? Even I rewrite the sessionDao to store the session in Memcache or Redis or JDBC, is it still store session in Ehcache?

And right now , I want implement a single sign on function(I have multiple web instances, and using round robin load balancer, two sessions will not create by the same instances), if the user login in Chrome, then the new login where kill all the other sessions created by other browsers,force the other browsers to logout, what is the best way to achieve this function using Shiro?

Answer (score 0):

No, Ehcache is NOT used by default.  You simply provide an implementation (so you could configure EhCache, Redis, etc)

Take a look at: https://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#enterprisecachesessiondao